# React Native ListView onEndReached fires automatically

Tags: javascript, android, listview, reactjs, react-native

I've made a list view with onEndReached property. In order to track how many times it triggers, I add a console.log in the _onEndReached function.

```
        <ListView
        initialListSize={1}
        dataSource={this.state.news}
        renderRow={this.renderNews.bind(this)}
        renderFooter={this.loadMore.bind(this)}
        onEndReached={this._onEndReached.bind(this)}
        onEndReachedThreshold={50}
        enableEmptySections={true} >
        </ListView>

       _onEndReached(){
       pager++;
       console.log('pager',pager);
       }
```

The weird thing is that the first time that listview is rendered, onEndReached will trigger 3 times although I never scroll on the screen.

P.S. the first render will save datasource in local storage.

[image]

But after the first render, every following render works fine. onEndreached will only triggers after I scroll to the bottom.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, did you fix this issue? i got the same problem